# Java @Remote and Marshaling Entity

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb

I trying to implement mechanism which will fetch data (Entity) from database through @Remote (RMI) invocation. I have the following classes:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "routes")
@XmlRootElement
public class Routes implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "aname")
    private String aname;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_context")
    private boolean isContext;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "editable")
    private boolean editable;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "assignable")
    private boolean assignable;
    @Column(name = "pattern")
    private String pattern;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "created")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_modified")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastModified;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "route")
    private List<BoxesItems> boxesItemsList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "targetRoute")
    private List<MenusItems> menusItemsList;
    @JoinColumn(name = "target_category", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Categories targetCategory;
    @JoinColumn(name = "target_page", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Pages targetPage;
    @JoinColumn(name = "modified_by", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Users modifiedBy;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "sessionTimeoutRedirect")
    private List<Settings> settingsList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "targetRoute")
    private List<Menus> menusList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "route")
    private List<SlidersItems> slidersItemsList;

..... getters and setter
```

Remote interface

```
@Remote
public interface RoutesFacadeRemote {

    int count();
    Routes getRoutePattern(String routeName);

 }
```

and service which implements remote interface

```
@Stateless
public class RoutesFacadeRe extends AbstractFacade<Routes> implements RoutesFacadeRemote {

    @Override
    public Routes getRoutePattern(String routeName) {
        return routesFacade.findByName(routeName);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have a problem with serialization during sending entity to the client. I get the following exception when executing method:

```
  javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
at org.shops.facades.remote._RoutesFacadeRemote_Wrapper.getRoutePattern(org/shops/facades/remote/_RoutesFacadeRemote_Wrapper.java)
at org.shops.it.hyperlink.CmsHyperlinkListIT.shouldBeAvaiableToSetHyperlinkListPage(CmsHyperlinkListIT.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:113)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
  Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:267)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:201)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
at org.shops.facades.remote.__RoutesFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.getRoutePattern(org/shops/facades/remote/__RoutesFacadeRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
... 33 more
   Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.valuehandlerReadException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:826)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:921)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:518)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:383)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:482)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:191)
... 36 more
  Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: WARNING: ORBIO00013: Stream corrupted
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.streamCorrupted(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2527)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectUsingFVD(IIOPInputStream.java:1627)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:348)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:311)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:277)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:819)
... 41 more
```

Exception not saying anythink that can help me to localize the problem. I discovered also that when I remove all relations to other entities in this entity everything works fine. Can someone have a similar problem and can help to figure out?? Kebaby There is somerhing like Cascade Serialization? Or similary.

All required fields annotated with @NotNull in entity Routes are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is because ORM returns not real object from database but Proxy. When starts your serialization transaction already close. But proxy is trying to initialize collection fields cause by default initializing is LAZY.

Try to invoke `EntityManager#detach(yourEntity)`